# Query concerning $\int\limits_0^\infty {{e^{\left( {it - 1} \right)x}}dx} = \frac{1} {{1 - it}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-distributions

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{\left( {it - 1} \right)x}}dx}  = \frac{1}
{{1 - it}}.$$

The above came up in a probability question and I was fairly happy it is true, I just don't really feel I understand properly when I go through step by step as follows.

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{\left( {it - 1} \right)x}}dx}  = 
\frac{1}{it-1} \left[ e^{\left( {it - 1} \right)x} \right]_0^\infty =
\frac{1}{it-1} \left( e^{\left( {it - 1} \right)\infty} - e^{\left( {it - 1} \right)0} \right)
$$
Once we get here we seem to say that $(it-1)\leq 1$, and I get that the real part is, because $e^{it}$ goes round the unit circle, but are we just ignoring the non-real part of it? It is a long time since I have done any complex analysis. I was looking at a characteristic function so $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and we are only looking at $x$ over $\mathbb{R}_+$. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Note $\lvert e^z\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} z}$. Now consider the integral up to some upper bound $R$, then you get $e^{(it-1)R}$, and $\lvert e^{(it-1)R}\rvert = e^{-R}$, which tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. So in a sense we are only interested in the magnitude of the complex number, or are only interested in the limit at $\infty$ which is in $\mathbb{R}$ when integrating over the reals. So if the limit was $i$ we would end up with something like $\frac{1+i}{it-1}$?

Comment: I don't understand the second part. Concerning the first part, here the magnitude suffices since the limit is $0$. Generally, evaluating $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ by plugging $F(\infty) - F(0)$ in is formally not without problems. You interpret $F(\infty)$ as $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} F(R)$, provided that limit exists (if it doesn't, your integral doesn't exist).

Comment: @DanielFischer OK Thanks.  Very useful comments.
The second part was trying to say that if $\lvert e^{(it-1)R}\rvert = e^{-R}+i$ then as $R\rightarrow\infty$ the integral would evaluate to $\frac{1-i}{it-1}$. Anyway thanks, you have told me what I wanted to know so if it was an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Off-topic, but I don't think I've ever seen "query" used in a mathematical context before. Thought I was on Stack Overflow for a second :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus proper deals only with integrals over a finite interval. When we use it to evaluate an integral over an infinite interval, say

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = F(\infty) - F(0),$$

where $F$ is a primitive of $f$, which we assume sufficiently regular, then this has to be interpreted as a limit,

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_0^R f(x)\,dx = \lim_{R\to\infty} F(R) - F(0),\tag{$\ast$}$$

where the integral exists - as an improper Riemann integral - by definition if and only if the first limit exists [and $f$ is Riemann integrable over every finite interval $[0,R]$; but to have a reasonable primitive such that the FTC makes sense, that is necessary]. Since the equality

$$\int_0^R f(x)\,dx = F(R) - F(0)$$

holds by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the first limit in $(\ast)$ exists if and only if the second limit exists. In that case, we interpret $F(\infty)$ as $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} F(R)$.

For the given integrand $e^{(it-1)x}$ here, we have $F(x) = \frac{1}{it-1}e^{(it-1)x}$, and we have $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} F(R) = 0$ since $\lvert e^z\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} z}$, and the real part of $(it-1)R$ tends to $-\infty$.